# Select records from parent table depending on a condition in child table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Order (parent) and Expedient (child)

Suppose this case:

```
Order
id |
order1 |

Expedient
id | order_id | status
1 | order1 | validated
2 | order1 | validated
3 | order1 | validated
4 | order1 | pending
```

I need a query that returns Order but only when the 4 child records are in state "validated"

If at least one of the records is in pending status, then no Order should be returned

I have tried with a subquery "NOT IN" excluding all pending expedients, but it's not working because always return me a Order

Comment: Show what you have tried. The `NOT IN` should work.

Comment: The data set appears designed such that a working query would return an empty result. This seems useless to the point of being perverse. Why not provide a comprehensive example? See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "I have tried with subquery ..."  I don't see a query!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using having count(status) >= 4

```
select  o.order_id 
from  `Order` o
INNER JOIN  Expedient e ON o.order_id = e.order_id
WHERE e.status = 'validated'
GROUP BY  o.order_id 
having count(e.status) >= 4
```

be careful using order as table name  you need  backtics ..and should be better use another name  .

and if you need  also pendind  = 0 then the having clause is

```
having count(e.status) >= 4 AND sum(status ='pending' )  =0
```

Comment: What if the number of sub-items in the order is not specifically `4`?

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word

Comment: @daShier  .. your comment is not clear to me ...  4  'validated'  value in status is the OP requirement

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: @scaisEdge the 4 records in the `Expedient` table may only be an _example_. What if another `order` has 3 child records?

Comment: if the order table has 3 chidl is not valid and is not returned ..

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the order's id then there is no need for a join:

```
select order_id
from Expedient
group by order_id
having sum(status = 'pending') = 0
```

I assume there are only the values `'validated'` and `'pending'` in the column `status`.
If you want exactly 4 rows with the value `'validated'` in `status`:

```
select order_id
from Expedient
group by order_id
having sum(status = 'pending') = 0 and sum(status = 'validated') = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

> If at least one of the records is in pending status, then no Order
>   should be returned

This is a case for a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
select o.*
from `Order` o
where not exists (
  select *
  from Expedient e
  where e.order_id = o.id
    and e.status = 'pending'
)
```

An equivalent method is an "anti-join":

```
select o.*
from `Order` o
left join Expedient e
  on  e.order_id = o.id
  and e.status = 'pending'
where e.order_id is null
```

For both queries you should have an andex on `Expedient(order_id, status [, other columns])` or `Expedient(status, order_id, [, other columns])`.

A `NOT IN` query might also work:

```
select o.*
from `Order` o
where o.id not in (
  select e.order_id
  from Expedient e
  where e.status = 'pending'
)
```

But note, that it might return nothing, if `Expedient.order_id` can be `NULL`. For this query you should have an index on `Expedient(status [, other columns])` - Ideally `Expedient(status , order_id, [, other columns])`.